# How to configure http2 within gatsby web application locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, http2

Currently I'm building webapp locally. How could we configure and test http/2 fot the app. Is there a plugin or extension which needs to be setup. Not using netlify for now.

Comment: Maybe this [link] (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/prpl-pattern/)  ?